# Postgresql how to remove duplicated rows by columns value from a table without index or id

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql,and I have a table named stock,this table has no index or id:

| open | high | low | close | volume | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 383.97 | 384.22 | 383.66 | 384.08 | 1298649 | 2022-12-16 14:25:00 |
| 383.59 | 384.065 | 383.45 | 383.98 | 991327 | 2022-12-16 14:20:00 |
| 383.59 | 384.065 | 383.45 | 383.98 | 991327 | 2022-12-16 14:20:00 |
| 383.59 | 384.065 | 383.45 | 383.98 | 991327 | 2022-12-16 14:20:00 |
| 383.64 | 384.2099 | 383.54 | 383.61 | 1439271 | 2022-12-16 14:15:00 |

How can I remove the rows that have duplicated datetime ,and only keep 1 row of it,only keep the latest row of it,by using Postgresql sql ?

The output should be:

| open | high | low | close | volume | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 383.97 | 384.22 | 383.66 | 384.08 | 1298649 | 2022-12-16 14:25:00 |
| 383.59 | 384.065 | 383.45 | 383.98 | 991327 | 2022-12-16 14:20:00 |
| 383.64 | 384.2099 | 383.54 | 383.61 | 1439271 | 2022-12-16 14:15:00 |

Something like:

```
delete from stock where datetime duplicated > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option to solve this problem is to:

- store one row of each of your duplicate records in a temporary table
- delete all records having duplicates from the original table
- adding duplicate records back from the temporary table to the original table

These steps can be condensed in the following three queries:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE deleted_values AS 
SELECT *
FROM tab
GROUP BY open, high, low, close, volume, datetime
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

DELETE FROM tab
USING deleted_values
WHERE tab.open = deleted_values.open
  AND tab.high = deleted_values.high
  AND tab.low = deleted_values.low
  AND tab.close = deleted_values.close
  AND tab.datetime = deleted_values.datetime;

INSERT INTO tab 
SELECT * FROM deleted_values;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nA4XiRbmA9QtzCC4ThPUC9/0).

Comment: If you can do it in Python + Pandas, as per your previous post, it's going to work definitely better than trying to do it in the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

As your table does not contain the *primary key* you'll have to use [`ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html)

This query reports the duplication "index" - all rows with `rn > 1` are duplicates

```
select ctid, tab.*,
row_number() over (partition by datatime order by open) rn
from tab;

ctid |open|datatime  |rn|
-----+----+----------+--+
(0,1)| 300|2022-12-16| 1|
(0,2)| 310|2022-12-16| 2|
(0,3)| 400|2022-12-17| 1|
(0,4)| 500|2022-12-18| 1|
(0,5)| 500|2022-12-18| 2|
```

Note that you set the `partition by` to your unique key and with `order by` you can controll which row will be preserved.

Than you use the `ctid`of the duplicated row to get rid of them

```
with t as (
select ctid, tab.*,
row_number() over (partition by datatime order by open) rn
from tab
)
delete from tab where ctid in (
   select ctid from t where rn > 1
);
-- 2 rows deleted
```

Sample (simplified) data

```
create table tab as 
select * from (values
(300, DATE'2022-12-16'),
(310, DATE'2022-12-16'),
(400, DATE'2022-12-17'),
(500, DATE'2022-12-18'),
(500, DATE'2022-12-18')
) tab(open, datatime)
;
```